# Looping statement

Tags: sql, loops, oracle11g, dbms-output

I am working on a loop to bring back the times tables from 1-12. I have completed this by using the following:

```
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..12
LOOP
FOR j IN (i)..12
LOOP
dbms_output.put_line ( (i ) || '*' || (j ) || ('=') || (i*j) );
END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

And it brings back:

```
1*1=1
1*2=2
1*3=3
1*4=4
1*5=5
1*6=6
1*7=7
1*8=8
1*9=9
1*10=10
1*11=11
1*12=12
2*2=4
2*3=6
2*4=8
etc..
```

it brings back all the times tables like i wanted. Now i want it to bring back a title for each set, how would i do this? for e.g.

```
1 timetable 
1*1=1
1*2=2
1*3=3
1*4=4
1*5=5
1*6=6
1*7=7
1*8=8
1*9=9
1*10=10
1*11=11
1*12=12
2 timestable
2*2=4
2*3=6
2*4=8
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try;

```
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..12 LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(to_char(i) || ' timetable');
        FOR j IN (i)..12 LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line ( (i ) || '*' || (j ) || ('=') || (i*j) );
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: That worked great! Thanks. I will accept the answer once 5 mins is up. Thanks for your help